# onFailure function in mqtt javascript client

Tags: mqtt, paho

I am using mqtt paho javascript client library to connect to an 
mqtt server,i am able to connect to server with username and password, now the issue is ...how can i warn user if he gives wrong username or password.[i followed this link](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/)
is there any onFailure function to report an error if user credentials are wrong??

```js
client.connect({onSuccess:this.onConnect.bind(this),userName:Name,password:Password},{onFailure:console.log("failed")});



  onConnect() {
  // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
  console.log("onConnect");
  
  }
```

> even though I am able to connect , I can see but "onConnect" and "failed" messages in my console

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the ***Connect Return code*** field  that the Broker will bring you

there is a list of constants defined in the protocol:

the one you are looking for is:

> **0x04 Connection Refused, bad user name or password**

other values specified are:

> 0x00: Connection Accepted
>
> 0x01: Connection Refused
>
> 0x02: Connection Refused
>
> 0x03: Connection Refused
>
> 0x04: Connection Refused
>
> 0x05: Connection Refused, not authorized
>
> from 6-255: Reserved for future use

Comment: could you please provide a sample how to read the Connect Return code field that the Broker is bringing .

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the docs [here](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/jsdoc/symbols/Paho.MQTT.Client.html#connect)

The Paho `connect` method takes an options parameter which includes a `onFailure` callback function which will include an error code for a authentication failure:

```
client.connect({
  onFailure: function(err) {
    if (err.errorCode == 0x4) {
      //bad user/password
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: client.connect({
  onFailure: function(err) {
    if (err.errorCode == 0x4) {
      //bad user/password
    }
  },
{onSuccess:this.onConnect.bind(this),userName:"user",password:"123"}});

Comment: I used the above code but i didn't get any error msg

Comment: That code won't show you an error, it just shows you where to handle the error, you have to add that bit yourself

Comment: i wrote " console.log(err); " in onFailure function ,but couln't see anything in console

Answer (score 0):

connect method takes connectionOptions as parameters so ,you can give options like onSuccess,onFailure,userName,password. A single response object parameter is passed to the onFailure callback that has fields like errorCode
,errorMessage.

```js
client.connect({onSuccess:this.onConnect.bind(this),
userName:uName,
password:uPassword,
onFailure:this.onFailure.bind(this)
});
onConnect() {
  // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
  console.log("onConnect");
     }
onFailure(responseObject){
  console.log("you have no access to the connnection!!!");
  console.log(responseObject);
 }
```